# Non Serializable item in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, serialization, spring-batch, deserialization

I recently came across Serializable interface and it looks like any object that has to be written to database or a file must implement interface. I created a spring batch job which reads from a table and writes to a file. The POJO class for item doesn't implement Serializable but the job still works. How is it able to read from data or write to a file in such a case?

Reader and writer -

```
    @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<MyObject> reader(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<MyObject> reader = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
        reader.setSql("SELECT val from value_table");
        reader.setDataSource(dataSource);
        reader.setRowMapper((resultSet, i) -> new MyObject(resultSet.getString("val")));
        return reader;
    }


    @Bean
    public FlatFileItemWriter<MyObject> writer() {
        FlatFileItemWriter<MyObject> writer = new FlatFileItemWriter<>();
        writer.setResource(new FileSystemResource("abc.txt"));
        writer.setAppendAllowed(true);
        writer.setLineSeparator("\n");

        DelimitedLineAggregator<MyObject> lineAggregator = new DelimitedLineAggregator<>();
        lineAggregator.setDelimiter(",");

        BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<MyObject> fieldExtractor = new BeanWrapperFieldExtractor<>();
        fieldExtractor.setNames(new String[]{"val"});

        lineAggregator.setFieldExtractor(fieldExtractor);
        writer.setLineAggregator(lineAggregator);
        return writer;
    }
```

POJO class -

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class MyObject {

    private String val;

}
```

Comment: " it looks like any object that has to be written to database or a file must implement interface". You are wrong. Only if you use the Java Serialization mechanism this is needed, and Java Serialization should be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the `FlatFileItemWriter`, the object is first transformed to a string with a `LineAggregator`, then the string is written to the file.

Domain objects do not have to be serializable, unless the Java serialization mechanism is used, be it in an item reader/writer, or in the execution context.